# Facebook compartilhar e verificar se compartilhou

Tags: facebook

Coloquei um botão de compartilhar, ele abre um nova janelinha para compartilhar o que eu defini, e se compartilhado eu faço uma ação, caso não tenha compartilhado, eu faço outro ação.

Porém, dá um erro nessa nova janela, do próprio facebook:

> Não é possível carregar a URL: O domínio dessa URL não está incluído
>   nos domínios do aplicativo. Para poder carregar essa URL, adicione
>   todos os domínios e subdomínios ao campo Domínios do aplicativo nas
>   configurações do aplicativo.

Já vi, verifiquei no meu app do facebook, no meu consenso está tudo correto.

Este é basicamente o código que estou utilizando(Vide JsFiddle tá rodando exatamente como eu defini no meu ambiente de teste):

https://jsfiddle.net/ezL1un3v/

***Qualquer informação, solicitar, realmente preciso solucionar este problema.***

Answer (score 1):

O `href` no seu código está para `www.google.com`, acredito que este seja o problema.
O seu app do facebook pode usar apenas os domínios que você configurou nele, para adicionar domínios você deve acessar seu app em `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/` e ir em `configurações` no menu.

Rolando abaixo você encontrará esta tela [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que terá que verificar seu(s) domínio(s), provavelmente não poderá referenciar domínios de terceiros.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Certamente eu fiz a configuração para o Google! Eu troquei agora para preservar o site do ambiente de produção, então coloquei o do Google. 

Sim, nos ajustes está configurado 'URL do site' para http://www.google.com/

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus faz um teste chamando a função sem o atributo `href`, assim será usado o valor padrão que é a própria URL em que você está, se funcionar significa que a URL que você passou para o `href` é o problema. Talvez seja apenas porque você não tenha adicionado um _subdomínio_.

Comment: Vou fazer o teste, vou editar no proprio jsfiddle. Fiz o teste: Acusou 'The parameter href is required'

Comment: Aqui está a configuração atual disposta no Facebook: http://ap.imagensbrasil.org/image/jqwObU

Comment: Verdade, ao usar o método `share` ele é obrigatório, a mensagem de erro continua me levando a pensar que o `href``seja o problema, eu tentaria colocar a url mais pura possível(sem sudomínios) do próprio domínio que você está e que tem certeza que está configurado no app. Mas não consigo imaginar outro problema que possa estar acontecendo.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus baseado na foto que enviou, tenta mudar a url do google para a do domínio que está o site, e referenciar o seu site no href. Para testar.
Eu tenho quase certeza que a URL que você configurar aí deve ser um domínio que você possui, e não de terceiros.

Comment: Pois é, como não existe verificar ou autenticar a URL para mostrar que o dominio é proprio, como no Youtube existe(para colocar URL clicavel no video), eu não penso que usar urls de terceiros seja de fato o problema.. Edit: Vou fazer o teste que indicou.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Mesmo que seja possível usar a URL de terceiros ali, estou quase certo que a sua URL do domínio que você está usando o app deve constar ali como forma de segurança.

Comment: Bom, coloquei a URL de produção, ajustei no facebook para URL de produção e fiz o teste na URL de produção(não no localhost e sim no próprio site online mesmo), e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Comment: Lucas, funcionou agora. Bom, eu não suspeitei que a solução poderia ser tão simples, e nem sabia que isso fazia alguma diferença(na verdade, se você puder me dizer porque disso, me fale!): No campo dominios do aplicativo, você deve colocar qual dominio está autorizado a usar seu aplicativo, basicamente se você indicar www.xx.com, o site xx.com não está autorizado. você precisa indicar tanto o xx.com quanto o www.xx.com... O maldito www faz a diferença, parece que existe a possibilidade de ser uma versão diferente do site. O que você acha desse comportamento?

Comment: Se existir a possibilidade de versões diferente com www, e sem www, então isso é justo. Tanto é que no Google console, quando você associa um site, ele pede para adicionar a versão com e sem www... No meu consentimento é o mesmo site, mas vi que pode ser uma versão diferente, será verdade?

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus, que bom que conseguiu!!! Existe sim a possiblidade de o site sem e com o www serem versões diferentes, claro que ficaria confuso pro usuário mas em termos de DNS são diferentes. o `www` funciona como um dos possíveis domínios do seu domínio principal.
Eu recomendo que você faça um `301 redirect` no seu site, dê uma olhada neste [artigo](http://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/o-que-e-o-redirect-301-e-porque-ele-e-um-bom-amigo-do-profissional-de-marketing/).